# Change duration of a performance monitor file using c#

Tags: c#, .net

How do I modify the " Duration"field of a performance monitor file in c#?

I have a custom performance monitor file. Which I have to open and modify the "duration" based on user input.

Can someone please help me with this? Thanks

Comment: Can you give us an example of the file and the code that you have tried? Help us, help you :)

Comment: Hi MattR, I am trying to automate this process and I use a custom ui tool to perform this task. I was wondering if this is possible using c#.